# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException: Add [title] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Post]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, api

Buenas tardes muchachos tengo este error que es muy comun al intentar agregar datos en masa a la BD, ya lei un poco sobre el, e intente acomodarlo pero no tengo exito!! quisiera que me ayudaran un poco a validar que estoy haciendo mal, o si estoy definiendo la variable bien...

esta funcion requiere es poder actualizar los campos seleccionados que serian titulo, contenido y categoria_id.

Mi controllador

PostController.php

```
public function update($id, Request $request){
    //recogerl os datos por post
        $json = $request->Input('json', null);
        $params= json_decode($json);
        $params_array = json_decode($json,true);

        $data=array(
            'code' => 400,
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Datos enviados incorrecto s'
        );

        if(!empty($params_array)){
        //Validar los datos
            $validate = \Validator::make($params_array,[
                    'title'=> 'required',
                    'content' => 'required',
                    'category_id' => 'required',

                ]);
        //guardar la categoria
            if ($validate->fails()) {
                $data['errors']= $validate->errors();
                return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
                    }
       //ELIMINAR ELEMENTOS
            unset($params_array ['id']);
            unset($params_array ['created_at']);
            unset($params_array ['user_id']);
            unset($params_array ['user']);

        //Actualizar el registro
            $post = Post::where('id', $id)->updateOrCreate($params_array);

        //Devolver Algo
        $data=array(
            'code' => 200,
            'status' => 'Success',
            'post' => $post,
            'changes' => $params_array,
        );
            
        }
        return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
    }
```

mi modelo

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = ['title'];
     

    //relacion de muchos a uno

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id ');
    }
    
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');;
    }

    
}
```

Imagen del error que aparece
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba indicando en el `$fillable` todos los atributos que serán masivamente asignados

Comment: Al asignarlo como indicas, da un error, normalmente solo deseo que el usuario que lo creo pueda actualizar los datos, pero que el user_id permanezca igual. Al aplicar el $fillable sin el campo user_id me daba un error, pero es un campo que no deseo actualizar, pero igual al no pasárselo por el formulario no lo actualiza y ya estaria realizando la función, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sustituye el `fillable[]`  por este atributo.

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Esto te permite guardar registros de forma masiva.

Comment: Es importante ser claro e indicarle que declarar un [`$guarded`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#allowing-mass-assignment) con un array vacío hace a todos los atributos blanco de asignación masiva